# Dual boot problem on Alienware R6 with Intel Optane

Tags: dual-boot, alienware

I'm trying to do dual boot Win 10 and Ubuntu on my Aurora R6 (with Intel Optane).

I followed following the instructions at
https://websetnet.com/install-ubuntu-linux-with-windows-10/.
In "installation type" step, the whole list is empty, I can't see any device.

Then I searched a lot, find maybe I should change SATA operation from RAID ON to ACHI in UEFI. I followed this instruction:
[Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 blocked: cannot find hard disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861404/installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-blocked-cannot-find-hard-disk)

And then, I can't boot win10 anymore, even with the recovery USB stick I prepared. Now the computer is completely dead...

Comment: No, the computer is not completely or partially dead. You can at any time change it back to the original settings and Windows will boot. *Then* you can install the AHCI drivers in Windows so you can change to that mode and have a working Windows. You shouldn't do certain things requiring a basic understanding before acquiring that basic knowledge.

Comment: @MichaelBay Many thanks for help.I changed the SATA operation back to RAID ON, but it doesn't work. It said can't boot the device, pls press any key to restart, something similar to this.

Comment: So far that's a Windows problem. Boot with a Windows installation disk or USB, repair Windows (or use the manufacturer's recovery) or anything for that purpose. Then try to install Ubuntu by following that guide but better to understand what your system has (UEFI) and what that mode entails (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI). Come back if you're stuck at some point (hopefully not). Windows and fixes for Windows are not supported here, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @MichaelBay I tried, but it can not reboot from usb right now, it said the drive is too small, something like that. That's why I call it dead...

Comment: Sorry if it sounds rude but the truth is: Not *our* problem. It's a Windows problem and we don't support Windows. And if you can't troubleshoot a Windows installation how do you expect to be able to understand what's needed to install Ubuntu in a dual boot configuration? I suggest you contact your tech support first for help with Windows recovery (and you can always reinstall Windows, you don' t even need a serial because with UEFI your Windows serial is stored in the firmware). Then you can start thinking about the dual boot.