# After installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using USB I can’t see my hard disk; it is not even displayed in Gparted

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, storage

I am not able to see my hard disk in disks.
I think I have accidentally formatted it but the hard disk is not listed even in the terminal. I tried otherwise I am now using Ubuntu without installation.

Has my hard disk been damaged? If that is the case what can I do, please?

Comment: Your computer Bios is maybe configured for RAID hard drive instead of ahci See this about Bios RAID setup. https://askubuntu.com/questions/861404/installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-blocked-cannot-find-hard-disk

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lshw -C storage`? Thanks.